# Attendance Import Issue in biometric Device Integration with Odoo

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'm using hr_biometric_machine module in odoo9.Installed and configure with same IP in two database.Run in first database and import attendance.i got the attendance entries upto that time.After sometime i run second database and import attendance i got the remaining that that uploaded in first db.The attendance entries that uploaded in second db is missing from first db.I need all attendance entries in both database.What should i do?
My connection is here,

```
zk = ZkOpenerp(ip_address, port)
conn = zk.connect()

class ZkOpenerp(ZK):

 def get_attendance(self):
    attendaces = super(ZkOpenerp, self).get_attendance()
    attendaces_openerp = []
    for attendace in attendaces:
        attendace_openerp = OpenerpAttendance(
            attendace.user_id, attendace.timestamp, attendace.status)
        attendaces_openerp.append(attendace_openerp)

    return attendaces_openerp
```

Below are the code of import attendance function

```
@api.model
def import_data(self):
    biometric_machine_obj = self.env['biometric.machine']
    biometric_user_obj = self.env['biometric.user']
    biometric_machines = biometric_machine_obj.search([])
    for biometric_machine in biometric_machines:
        self.import_data_classmethod(
            biometric_machine, self, biometric_user_obj, )
```

please check

```
   @classmethod
   def import_data_classmethod(
        cls, biometric_machine, biometric_data_obj, biometric_user_obj, ):
    attendances = biometric_machine.getattendance()
    # Sorted elements using user_id and timestamp
    attendances.sort(key=lambda x: (x.user_id, x.timestamp))
    for attendance in attendances:
        user = biometric_user_obj.search([
            ['biometric_id', '=', int(attendance.user_id), ], ], )
        if not attendance.action_perform:
            continue
        if not user.employee_id:
            biometric_data_obj.create(
                {'biometric_user_id': user.id,
                 'datetime': attendance.timestamp,
                 'action_perform': attendance.action_perform, }, )
            continue
```